# How to migrate a question

Tags: support, migration

I often have security questions about risk managment which involve
considering technical details at the operating system level.
These technical details are necessary to evaluate
correctly which risk I am talking of and how to attack their reduction.
I want to avoid any form of theoretical or opinion based discussion.

How may I migrate this kind of question to another discussion group?

Which group would be better suited to get a correct risk evaluation aware
answer with technical details taking into account the basic weaknesses of
the targeted OS?

A practical example is the question
[Skype removal on Windows](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/45772/9792).

How may I move it to the Super User group?

Is this the relevant group to get the better suited answer?

Comment: not sure exactly what you are asking. Do you mean you want to know how to migrate a question from this site to another? Or are you talking about discussion groups (like [chat])?

Comment: If the former, we don't support opinion based discussion (and in fact we discourage discussion at all on SE sites) as we aim for specific answers to specific questions.

Comment: If you are referring to your Skype question, it was closed as off topic because we don't do questions on how to install/remove or how to configure software applications. The close reason suggests asking it on Super User instead.

Comment: → Rory[1st comment]: What I'm asking are the 2 sentences in english ending with a question mark ☺.
Yes (correct understanding). No (no chat).

Comment: I think the confusing part is calling Stack Exchange sites "groups". These are very definitely NOT discussion groups, this is not just semantics. Please see [About]. Specifically regarding your Skype question, it was a "how to" question (which we don't cover), and very distinctly NOT a risk analysis / risk management question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How may I migrate this kind of question to another discussion group?

- If you have at least 3000 reputation: click the “close” button on the question, select “off-topic”, then “This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network” and the desired target site.
- If you have less than 3000 reputation: click the “flag” button , then select “it should be closed for another reason...”, then “off-topic” and continue as above.
- If the desired site doesn't appear in the list, or if the question is already closed, click “flag”, “other”, and explain what you want a moderator to do and why.

By the way, on Stack Exchange, there are no discussion groups. Stack Exchange is a network of [questions and answers](https://security.stackexchange.com/about) sites. Calling them “group” or “site” is a matter of terminology, but the difference between discussion and Q&A is important.

> Which group would be better suited to get a correct risk evaluation aware answer with technical details taking into account the basic weaknesses of the targeted OS?

This site is the right place.

But the [question you link to](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45772/skype-removal-on-windows) is not about getting a risk evaluation. It's about how to accomplish a particular task, and the task is a system administration task, not a security task. This is the job of a system administrator, not the job of a security professional. That's why this question is off-topic here. The question would be on-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), a site for computer users and amateur administrators, or possibly on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), a site for professional system administrators dealing with enterprise software and hardware.

Given that the question has not been answered, migration is overcomplicating things a bit. You might as well repost the question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).